# About $O_X$-modules?

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, derived-functors

Consider $F$ an $O_X$-module is true in general that $Hom_{O_X}(O_X,F) \equiv F(X)$ ?
Morover I need to prove that if $F$ is a flasque sheaf then $H^n(X,F)=0$ for $n>0$.

I think is beacuse the fact that the section functor $\Gamma(U,-)$ keeps an exact sequence of sheaves $$ 0 \to F \to I \to H \to 0  
$$ to an exact sequence 
$$
 0 \to \Gamma(U,F) \to \Gamma(U,I) \to \Gamma(U,H) \to 0
$$
This implies that the derived functors $R\Gamma$ are all $0$  it is correct?
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: For your first question, yes $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{F}(X)$. This is a good exercice to construct the bijection with these two groups. The second question is more difficult but there is a proof in any books on the subject. Do you have a difficulty with the proof ?

Comment: The main problem was the first point but i wan try by myself, for the second part my purpose wa to understand better the proof in the Hartshorne's book.